# Does the Targetteer variant Fighter's Sniper ability actually require you to make attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, fighter

Dragon magazine issue 310 introduces the Targetteer variant of the Fighter class, which has the following bonus feat option:

> *Sniper:* When using the full attack option the targetteer can sacrifice attacks to gain deadly accuracy. For each attack from a full attack sacrificed, the threat range of the targetteer's weapon increases by 1.

What I'm wondering, though, is whether or not this actually requires the character to fire their weapon on each sacrificed attack. Suppose a character is wielding two double crossbows from the web enhancement Races of the Dragon, Part 2, which each let the wielder make an extra attack at their highest BAB, but all of their attacks that round take a -2 penalty. By RAW that character can make four attacks per round (at a significant penalty to hit), and could sacrifice three of them to improve the critical hit range of the last one.

However, does this action consume one bolt or four? Also, since they only made one attack, are they spared the longer reload time for the double crossbows?

Comment: (An Aside: The real question is how a professional magazine let the word *targeteer* be misspelled *and* misused throughout the entire article. *Sigh.*)

Comment: @HeyICanChan it’s a gendered thing. The targeteer shots at targets. The targetteer shooters at targettes.

Answer (score 11):

We have nothing to go on beyond what you have quoted. There is no game definition of “sacrificed attacks.” But the only thing that makes sense to me is that sacrificed attacks are attacks you do not make. The bolts stay where they are, loaded in the crossbows. If you were supposed to make the attacks, but they automatically miss or something, that would have a lot of additional ramifications that would need to be spelled out and the ability doesn’t.

So I think it works, and it’s a neat trick. But it’s also still a bad trade—for attacks you could have made, anyway. With thanks to @minnmass for doing the math, you are more likely to get at least one critical hit without sniper than with it so long as you use a weapon with a 19-20 threat range or better. And that’s *at least one*—actually making the attacks gives you a chance to make more than one, while that isn’t possible if you’re sacrificing all of your attacks to expand your threat range as much as possible.

The key thing here, to me, is that the ability never specifies *which* attacks you sacrifice. Sacrificing an attack with a good chance to hit is a bad idea. Sacrificing your third iterative that has a −15 penalty? That’s a much better-sounding trade. Still, that’s at high levels, and at high levels this has to compete with Improved Critical or *keen*, since sniper does not stack with those. Sniper is generally going to lose that competition.

There are some advantages to one big hit, rather than many, smaller hits, per @Prevarications’s comment, but since we are more likely to see a critical hit by attacking more, *at best* we should sacrifice just one attack to achieve 19-20 threat range if our weapon has a usual threat range of just 20.

The more important thing that @Prevarications points out is that there is no requirement that the sacrificed attacks be ranged attacks.¹ If you have natural weapons as a ranged attacker, those are melee-only attacks that you might not be within reach to make, so those can be “freely” sacrificed. In other words, you pulled the wrong thing from [that web enhancement](https://web.archive.org/web/20200315192332/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060420a)—what you really want is the kobold and its claw/claw/bite natural weapons. Converting a 20/×4 weapon into a 17-20/×4 weapon isn’t terrible for the cost of a race that’s quite decent in other respects, and a level of fighter (or the feat you might otherwise have gotten with that level). It’s not great, either, but natural weapons are relatively easy to come by,² so you can easily expand it past 17-20; you could even do better than the 15-20 range available by just taking Improved Critical on an 18-20 weapon.

Unfortunately, there is only one ranged weapon that gets a ×4 multiplier, the exotic war sling from *Races of the Wild*. The war sling is an interesting weapon—if you have proficiency with both it and skiprocks, you can launch a skiprock with the war sling and ricochet it off of your first target and into the next. Doubling your attacks per turn is a great thing to do when crit-fishing, and if sniper lets you get a solid critical hit range, that’s pretty awesome. And the targeteer gets proficiency in any two ranged exotic weapons—like the war sling and skiprock!

From there, the deepwood sniper from *Masters of the Wild* is probably the way to go. Its keen arrows effect arguably **does** stack with sniper (though this is because it’s a 3.0e prestige class so your DM may well amend this—ultimately it’s fairly minor either way), and then its projectile improved critical ability increases the ×4 multiplier to ×5 at 2nd and ×6 at 7th.

Other than those, you definitely want Dead Eye from *Dragon Compendium* (note the errata changes the BAB +14 requirement to BAB +1!), and ranged attack mainstays like Point-Blank Shot, Precise Shot, and Rapid Shot. Targeteer can help with any of those. So can psychic warrior, which has the added bonus of also having access to a bunch of abilities to get more natural weapons to sacrifice for sniper. You’ll also probably want to dip warblade or swordsage (*Tome of Battle*) for the *blood in the water* Tiger Claw stance.

In all, a kobold-playing-to-their-strengths targeteer/deepwood sniper with a war sling and skiprocks is probably winds up being one of the *most* effective ways to play a pure damage-dealing ranged-attack character, shockingly enough.

1. <sub>There’s no requirement that the attacks *you actually make* be ranged, either, for that matter.</sub>
2. <sub>As examples, the kobold qualifies for the Dragon Tail feat from *Races of the Dragon*, 1000 gp can buy the *mighty arms* graft from *Faiths of Eberron* (though this might not stack with claws), Bind Vestige + Practiced Binder from *Tome of Magic* allows a ram attack from Amon. Illithid Grapple from *Complete Psionic* can be taken up to 4 times for up to 4 tentacle attacks, but it requires Illithid Heritage and another illithid feat, so that’s pricey. If you’re looking to invest that much, you’d do much better just taking 2 levels of totemist from *Magic of Incarnum*. With that, you can easily shape *chaos roc’s span* (*Dragon* vol. 350) and *dragon tail* (*Dragon Magic*), and bind *girallon arms* (*Magic of Incarnum*), for 7 natural weapons (2 wing buffets, tail slap, and 4 claws) and at that point you don’t even need to be a kobold (though it would add a bite).</sub>

Comment: I think the idea is that it's for overcoming high DR enemies, which are normally the bane of archers' existences. It's not as good as something like Pathfinder's clustered shots feat, but it's something. There's also some synergy with weapon enchantments like *fiery burst* and so forth, though those are all bad. And lastly, because I do agree that this uses only one arrow, it's useful for conserving special ammo. Interestingly, the sacrificed attacks don't have to be ranged attacks, so if you have secondary natural weapons, you can sack those for bonus crit range—though that's a bit cheesy.

Comment: @Prevarications Very clever on the natural attacks angle, I do like that. And yes, it helps a bit in the case of DR, but since it’s not increasing the multiplier, it’s not helping _much_. Clustered Shots is a vastly superior solution, so if DR was the impetus here, I’d strongly recommend requesting to backport it—and I’d strongly suggest that all reasonable DMs should allow it.

Comment: With a threat range of 20, increasing the range increases the number of crits - 2 attacks have a 90.25% chance of no crits (https://anydice.com/program/910a) where 1 attack with a 19-20 range has a 90% chance of no crits; attacking 3x has an 85.74% chance of no crits, where 1 attack with an 18-20 has an 85% chance of no crits. With a normal range of 19-20, critting decreases: 2 attacks have an 81% chance of no crits, where an 18-20 has an 85% chance of no crits (https://anydice.com/program/d74a).

Comment: @minnmass Thanks. The double crossbow mentioned in the question has 19-20, so yeah, doesn’t help for that. Really, if you care about getting crits, particularly _at least one crit_, then you’d be hard-pressed to justify anything but 18-20. I guess the double crossbow kinda offers a reason.

Comment: Am I missing where the special ability sniper that says that a targetteer (ugh—the name!) *must* use a ranged weapon to benefit from the ability? A DM may rule it's ranged weapons only because the example has a targetteer using a ranged weapon and the names, but it doesn't seem a *technical* requirement. (Just in case I *am* overlooking something, let me be helpful so no one chases geese: the war sling is from *Races of the Wild* not *the Dragon* and is likely supposed to—but because naming conventions doesn't—supersede the halfling warsling (n.b. spelling) from *Races of Faerûn*.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, at one point I even had a parenthetical pointing that out, but I removed it since it made the sentence clunky. If you’re in melee anyway, giving up natural weapon attacks is more dubious (though still plausible, e.g. for the 1d3 secondary weapons that the kobold has). And whoops, yes, I’ll correct the citation for the war sling.

Comment: Still, if *any* weapon can be used in conjunction with sniper then thrown weapons—perhaps made of Kaorti resin—become an option.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Right, but deepwood sniper requires a projectile weapon, so that becomes a rather different build. Bloodstorm blade and master thrower probably come in at that point, and the targeteer (I refuse) trick becomes kind of just “another thing” you’re doing. Especially with Kaorti resin; at that point you can have a native 18-20/×4 weapon and Improved Critical gets you to 15-20/×4—sniper can beat that, but it takes a lot more investment.

Comment: Totally fair. Practicality be damned, I was amused by the kobold totemist/targeteer that dumps, like, 7 natural attacks to throw a *+1 prismatic burst shuriken* or a *+1 burst burst burst burst Kaorti razor net* or whatever. But I'm sure you're right that the math will prove the concept suboptimal when enough other parts are moving. Thank you for indulging my speculation.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I mean, 2 levels of totemist easily gets you there (and doesn’t even really need kobold at that point), and yeah, that’s pretty good. Palm throw is going to double your attacks, and without the limitations of skiprocks (though you could easily throw those, if you wanted—or better, go for Boomerang Ricochet and Boomerang Daze). It’s not that it won’t work—it’s just that, if anything, the other things going on are stronger and make sniper less of a star.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you'd be "sacrificing" an attack you couldn't otherwise make (because no targets are in range or, worse, because you can't do claw attacks while wielding a weapon in those hands). And, without any definition of what sacrificing attacks might possibly mean, I guess we will never know.

Comment: @Zachiel Agreed about attacks with hands that are occupied, that’s a good point. But you can always attack the ground, even if nothing else is in range, so the melee attacks are definitely valid.